# Polymorphic casting from void*

Tags: c++

See code below for the details, but the underlying scenario is as follows. I have a container (a session) that I can place objects in and pull out from.

Similar to:

```
 std::shared_ptr<Tiger> t = ...;
 session.store("tigers/1", t);

 std::shared_ptr<Tiger> t2 = session.load<Tiger>("tigers/1");
```

With both functions defined as:

```
 class Session { 
      template<class T> 
      void store(std::string id, std::shared_ptr<T> instance);

      template<class T> 
      std::shared_ptr<T> load(std::string id);
 }
```

Note that a session can store heterogeneous types, but at `store` and `load` time I statically known what the type of the variable is.

My problem is that I run into a situation where the user wants to put a `Tiger` into the session but checks out a base type, instead. For example:

```
  session.load<Animal>("tigers/1");
```

Right now, I'm effectively storing the data as `void*` inside the session and use `reinterpret_cast` to get them back to the user provided type. This... works, as long as everything is trivial, but when we get to a slightly more complex situation, we run into issues.

Here is the full code demonstrating my issue:

```
struct Animal
{
    virtual void Pet() const = 0;
};

struct IJumpable
{
    virtual void Jump() const = 0;
};

struct Tiger : Animal, IJumpable
{
    void Pet() const override
    {
        std::cout << "Pet\n";
    }

    void Jump() const override
    {
        std::cout << "Jump\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto cat = std::make_shared<Tiger>();

    // how the data is stored inside the session
    auto any_ptr = std::static_pointer_cast<void>(cat);
    // how we get the data out of the session
    auto namable = std::static_pointer_cast<IJumpable>(any_ptr);

    namable->Jump();
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

If you run this code, you'll see that it runs, but instead of calling `Jump`, it calls to `Pet`. I understand that this is because of the wrong virtual method table being used, since I'm effectively calling `reinterpret_cast` on `void*.

My question is if there is a good way to handle this scenario in C++. I've looked around and didn't see anything that matches what I need.

Everything I found about heterogeneous containers always assumed a shared base class, which I don't have nor want. Is this possible?

Comment: Is it assured that in `Session` class, you will store only base types of `Animal`?

Comment: If you know the types you store beforehand, maybe you want to take a look at std::variant.

Comment: No, you can store _anything_ there.

Comment: I don't know what the types that would be stored in here. The caller may put `Tiger`, `Car` or `FancyWidget`, etc.

Comment: Are the stored types known statically? If so, can you use `std::variant`? If not, can you use `std::any`?

Comment: @KrzysiekKarbowiak I can't use `std::any`, because the types do not match. 

`auto cat = new Tiger();

auto any_ptr = std::any(cat);

auto namable = std::any_cast<IJumpable*>(any_ptr);
`

This will result in bad cast

Comment: @AyendeRahien The conversion will be undefined more often than not. We are not storing type info at all.

Comment: I'm fine with storing type, but I don't know _how_ to do that or how to get it out properly. I thought about using a lambda to capture the type, but I don't know how to get the destination type to it properly

Comment: @AyendeRahien You may store `typeid` but that will lead to lot of ifs which will be handled by the user of the class. By the way, Why do you need such a thing?

Comment: This is an OR/M library. I have this in C# and user can do that easily using `Load<T>` and casting from `object` to `T`, I'm trying to see how I can do the same in C++ port of the library

Comment: @AyendeRahien Why can't you create your own wrappers which inherit from a common type? Like `Integer` wrapping an `int` and inheriting from `Object` class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186121/discussion-between-ayende-rahien-and-kunal-puri).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution courtesy of my brother who happens to be a C++ expert with no stackoverflow :)

Here is a `void_ptr` implementation that enables polymorphic casting using exception handling to discover types. The performance should be close to that of a dynamic_cast. You should be able to optimize the above using `std::type_index` and caching the offsets.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class void_ptr {
  void* obj;
  void (*discover_type)(void*);

  template<typename T>
  static void throw_typed_object(void* obj)
  {
    T* t = static_cast<T*>(obj);
    throw t;
  }
public:

  void_ptr() : obj(0) {}

  template<typename T>
  void_ptr(T* t) : obj(t), discover_type(throw_typed_object<T>)
  {
  }

  template<typename T>
  T* cast() const
  {
    try {
      discover_type(obj);
    } catch(T* t) {
      return t;
    } catch(...) {
    }
    return 0;
  }
};

struct Animal {
  virtual ~Animal() {}
  virtual const char* name() { return "Animal"; }
};

struct Speaker {
  virtual ~Speaker() {}
  virtual const char* speak() { return "hello"; }
};

struct Lion : public Animal, public Speaker {
  virtual const char* name() { return "Lion"; }
  virtual const char* speak() { return "Roar"; }
};


int main()
{
  void_ptr ptr(new Lion());


  Animal* a = ptr.cast<Animal>();
  Speaker* s = ptr.cast<Speaker>();

  printf("%s\n", a->name());
  printf("%s\n", s->speak());
}
```

Comment: Wow, I'm not sure if I'm in awe or scared from this code. This is going to require some meditating upon. Very cool

Comment: Thanks @AyendeRahien - updated code to throw and catch pointer instead of reference since with ref copy constructor is called.

Answer (score 6):

You could make the user provide you with the correct casting trek to follow:

```
class Session { 
      template<class T> 
      void store(std::string id, std::shared_ptr<T> instance);

      template<class T> 
      std::shared_ptr<T> load(std::string id);

      template<class Stored, class Retrieved>
      std::shared_ptr<Retrieved> load_as(std::string id) {
          auto stored = load<Stored>(id);
          return std::static_pointer_cast<Retrieved>(stored);
      }
 }
```

This makes a messy usage at the caller site, but the information *must* come from somewhere:

```
auto shere_khan = make_shared<Tiger>();
session.store("tigers/1", shere_khan);
auto bagheera = session.load_as<Tiger, IJumpable>("tigers/1");
```

Comment: Can primitives be stored using this way?

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IMO best solution is not to cast to pointer to `void` but to other type which can be [dynamic sidecast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to required type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Animal
{
    virtual ~Animal() {}
    virtual void Pet() const = 0;
};

struct IJumpable
{
    virtual ~IJumpable() {}
    virtual void Jump() const = 0;
};

struct IStrorable
{
    virtual ~IStrorable() {}
};

struct Tiger : Animal, IJumpable, IStrorable
{
    void Pet() const override
    {
        std::cout << "Pet\n";
    }

    void Jump() const override
    {
        std::cout << "Jump\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto cat = std::make_shared<Tiger>();

    auto any_ptr = std::static_pointer_cast<IStrorable>(cat);

    auto namable = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<IJumpable>(any_ptr);

    namable->Jump();
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VQCRsQijFEl17gfe)

Other solutions require use of `std::any`, but this will be less handy.

It is a bit disturbing that your method `load` is a template.

Comment: My problem is that I don't control the types that are provided me (they are done by the caller, and I don't want to limit them)

Comment: How would you provide a type to the `load` method, since it needs to be able to provide any type back?